# how to obtain the count of numeric variables in a csv file using R

Tags: r

how to obtain the count of numeric variables in a csv file using R
So I'm having 28 columns with numeric variables and some categorial variables. I know I could use class(datasheet$variablename) to find out if a specific variable is integer or factor. But I have multiple columns and I'm wondering if there's a quicker way to count how many numeric variables do I have in total.

Completely new to R. Really just expecting some beginner functions and coding. Any advice will help and really appreciate!

Comment: Do you mean `str(datasheet)` ?

Comment: Maybe `table(sapply(datasheet, class))`? It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Yeah thanks Jared, I tried str() function and this looks like a list of the data types of all the variables. It is fine but I just needed counts of each class.

Comment: And MrFlick that table is perfect and thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
datasheet<-read.csv('filename.csv')
```

```
sapply(datasheet, is.numeric)
```

to tell which variables are numeric

```
sum(sapply(datasheet, is.numeric))
```

will tell you how many are numeric